# Command Cool-down not recognizing ctx

Tags: python, discord.py

Okay so basically, I wrote this code and it is saying

```
File "C:\Users\jellis\Desktop\Suggestion Bot\bot.py", line 28, in <module>
    @commands.cooldown(1, 1500, ctx)
NameError: name 'ctx' is not defined
```

I've tried moving `@commands.cooldown(1,1500 ctx)` to after the `async def suggest(ctx, *args)` but it gave the same error.

```py
@bot.command(pass_context = True)
@commands.cooldown(1, 1500, ctx)
async def suggest(ctx, *args):

    mesg = ' '.join(str(*args))
    embed = discord.Embed(title='New Suggestion', description='-----------', color=0x4C4CE7)

    if chatFilter in mesg:
        await bot.say(':x: Suggestion Could Not Be Sent.')
    elif chatFilter not in mesg:
        embed.add_field(name='{}'.format(ctx.message.author.display_name), value='{}'.format(mesg))
        await bot.send_message(discord.Object(id=suggestionsChannelID), embed=embed)

        white_check_mark = get(bot.get_all_emojis(), name='white_check_mark')
        await bot.add_reaction(message, white_check_mark)

        x = get(bot.get_all_emojis(), name='x')
        await bot.add_reaction(message, x)
        suggestionCount = suggestionCount + 1
    else:
        raise error


@bot.error
async def bot_error(error, member: discord.Member, ctx):
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandOnCooldown):
        msg = ':x: {member} This command on cooldown, please try again in `{:.2f}s`'.format(error.retry_after)
        await bot.send_message(ctx.message.channel, msg)
    else:
        raise error
```

I expected it to detect that the command is on cooldown and then run the `@bot.error` event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your cooldown will never be activated and will always run into an Error.
Because, since ctx is the Context-Container of your Bot and must not go there as Property.

The @commands.cooldown is specified as follows:

```
discord.ext.commands.cooldown(rate, per, type=<BucketType.default: 0>)
```

You have to pass an Enum with the Bucket you want to use instead of the Context-Container (ctx).

Usable Buckets you can use are:

```
BucketType.default for a global basis.

BucketType.user for a per-user basis.

BucketType.guild for a per-guild basis.

BucketType.channel for a per-channel basis.

BucketType.member for a per-member basis.

BucketType.category for a per-category basis.
```

For further Information you can find the [Discord Documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) here.